# Pushkin fails to initialize PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am following the [Pushkin Quickstart guide](https://pushkin-social-science-at-scale.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/gettingstarted.html).

At `pushkin init site`, I get an error that no container was found for test_db_1:

```
...
Pulling test_db (postgres:11)...
11: Pulling from library/postgres
Digest: sha256:8e096175da9b7a1d5f073e4ff0b2058a68b3110dc9c26bcee0975d25ad1c008e
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:11
Creating pushkin_test_db_1       ... done
Creating pushkin_message-queue_1 ... done
Creating pushkin_api_1           ... done
Creating pushkin_server_1        ... done
Starting test_db ... done
Creating local test database
No container found for test_db_1
Failed to run create database command in test_db container: 1
```

If I open Docker Desktop > pushkin > pushkin_test_db_1 > Logs, I see

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified. 
You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the superuser. 
For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run". 
You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all connections without a password. 
This is *not* recommended. See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust": 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

I tried opening ./pushkin.yaml, adding a password there, and running `pushkin init site` but nothing has changed. My guess is that the command represented by `Creating pushkin_test_db_1` doesn't provide Docker a password to the database. Looking on the [postgres github](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/681), this behavior seems to be a new "feature."

Does anyone have a recommendation to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a fix. First, I deleted all of the old docker containers to prevent conflicts when trying to create new ones. Then, from a new directory, I ran `pushkin site default` to initialize the filesystem. Next, in `./pushkin/docker-compose.dev.yml`, update `services: test_db` to look like the following:

```
  test_db:
    image: 'postgres:11'
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpassword
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'test_db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

This will provide a password for the postgres database so that it doesn't complain. It looks like this could be easily updated at the source so that when `pushkin site default` downloads temp.zip, this change is already implemented in the yaml file.

Comment: Are you sure it's the password? Or the fact that you deleted all the old docker containers?

Comment: I tried deleting all the old docker containers already and that didn't help. The error message was pretty clear that postgresql needs a password to initialize the database. I know error messages aren't perfect, but this interpretation is supported by the discussion I linked in my original post -- that the postgresql developers recently implemented this requirement.

Comment: Yes @MattGraham, There are some recent changes in postgres images on dockerhub

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronization problem with the CLI. Sometimes, simply running "pushkin init site" again works. Try that and let me know if you get a different error.

Comment: I've tried multiple times with the same result. I think a found a solution though. See (below)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/61173783/13000676]

Answer (score 0):

What the pushkin init site command does is download all the dependencies the pushkin project needs. You may want to continue the following steps on the quick start and see if things go well.

And for this issue, try to run `docker-compose -f pushkin/docker-compose.dev.yml exec -T test_db psql -U postgres -c "create database test_db` and `docker-compose -f pushkin/docker-compose.dev.yml stop test_db` to see if anything change.

Comment: I think there's a double quote missing at the end of the first command. After running it though, I'm getting "ERROR: No container found for test_db_1"